# Find the orthogonal projection matrix $ \ P_V \ $ onto $ \ V \subset \mathbb{R}^4 \ $ so that $ \large \ z=P_V \ y \ $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ \ V \ $ be a subspace of $ \ \mathbb{R}^4 \ $ spanned by the vectors $ v_1=(1,0,1,1) \ $ and $ \ v_2=(2,1,0,-1) \ $

Let $ \ y=(-1,1,-2,0) \in \mathbb{R}^4 $ .

(i)  Find the point $\ \large z \in V \ $ which is closest to the point $ \ y \ $.

(ii) Find the orthogonal projection matrix $ \ P_V \ $  onto $ \ V \subset \mathbb{R}^4 \ $ so that $ \large \ z=P_V \ y \ $

**Answer:**

(i) I have found the closest point $ \ z \in V \ $ from $ \ y \ $ \ is

$ z=(-4/3, -1/6,-1, -5/6) \ $

(ii) **How to find orthogonal projection matrix** $ P_V \ $ ?

Is it  $ z=P_V \ y \ \Rightarrow y=P_V^{-1} \ z \ $

**Please help me for the part (ii).**

Comment: That’s not the closest point to $y$. How did you come up with that vector?

Comment: taking projection of $ y \ $ on $ V \ $

Comment: Then you did it wrong, since that’s not the orthogonal projection of $y$ onto $V$.

Comment: so what would be the closest point ?

Comment: Instead of my simply handing you the answer, update your question with your work so that we might spot your error.

Answer (score 1):

$P^{-1}_V$ will not exist, as the range of $P_V$ is $V$, not $\mathbb{R}^4$.

To compute the matrix for this transform, follow the usual procedure. Compute the closest points of the standard basis $(1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)$, and put the results as columns into a matrix.

Comment: But $ V \ $ is spanned by only two vectors . so why we have to find out the closest distances from the standard basis. ?

Comment: Sure, but $P_V$ is an operator on all of $\mathbb{R}^4$. We care about the result of the projection outside of $V$ (in fact, if we restricted it to $V$, we would get the identity!).