# orthogonal projection matrix of $ (-2,2,-4,0)$ onto $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ \ V \ $ be a two dimensional subspace of $ \ \mathbb{R}^4 \ $ spanned by the vectors $ (1,0,1,1)$ and $(-2,1,0,-1).$ Find the orthogonal projection matrix  of $ (-2,2,-4,0)$ onto $V$.

**Answer:**

I am not sure but tried in the following way:

$$ \text{projection of } (-2,2,-4,0) \text{ on } (1,0,1,1) \\ = (-2,0,-2,-2) \\ \text{projection of } (-2,2,-4,0) \text{ on } (-2,-1,0,-1) \\ =(0,0,0,0) $$

**But I got stuck here.**

I don't have idea what to do next.

**Help me out.**

Comment: You projected $(-2, 2, -4, 0)$ onto $(1, 0, 1, 1)$ and got two different answers?

Comment: The projection of $v$ along $a$ is given by $$\frac{\langle v,a\rangle}{\|a\|^2}a.$$  Now use linearity.

Comment: how will use that

Comment: The sentence “Find the orthogonal projection matrix of $(-2,2,-4,0)$ onto $V$.” doesn’t make sense. Do you want to find the projection matrix, the projection of this vector onto $V$, or both?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe “Use linearity” only works when the basis is orthogonal, which it isn’t here.

Comment: This is virtually identical to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2496059/265466). The only difference is that the vector you’re projecting is $2$ times the original vector.

Comment: You say that $V$ is generated by $(-2,1,0,-1)$, but you compute the projection onto $(-2,-1,0,-1)$. Which is it? In neither case is the dot product with $(-2,2,-4,0)$ equal to zero, so the zero vector can’t be the correct projection, anyway.